# Is there a way to create a permanent virtual USB drive in WIndows?

Tags: windows, boot, usb, uefi

Is there a way to create a virtual USB drive, through some UEFI magic that stays there during boot and would be bootable? I have seen recovery programs do this where they create a virtual USB drive or something like it then boot from that virtual USB drive without ever actually needing to have a USB drive connected to the system. I am assuming you would create a partition on the main drive, somehow trick the UEFI BIOS into thinking that it is a USB drive and make it bootable. Is this possible?

Essentially we need to make a partition on the hard drive that acts as a USB drive, and boot from it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb

Comment: Agreed, Unetbootin is your best bet. I've done it several times with Linux distros I wanted to keep as back-up in case my Windows copies went berserk. However, you must add arguments to the Unetbootin shortcut to make this work as indicated in the answer Wasif pointed you to. See here for more details (look for "installtype" and "targetdrive"): https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/commands/

Comment: Thanks. How does this program work? I’m curious.

Comment: I know this can be done via grub, perhaps you need to use grub vs windows boot mgr